# how to stop asking OTP each time i open the app in android studio using Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, one-time-password

I just created an app where users can log in through OTP. but the problem is;  After the first-time login by phone otp. when i close the app it. and start again the app. it starts from the start like entering the phone number and sent otp. how to stop this and retrieve data as I before log in

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on your OTP and verification activity

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentuser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(currentuser != null)
    {
        // send user to mainactivity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Before you goto login page, check if user has logged in.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```